# Overloading (+)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to define a `Vector3` data type in Haskell and allow the `(+)` operator to be used on it. I tried the following:

```
data Vector3 = Vector3 Double Double Double    
Vector3 x y z + Vector3 x' y' z' = Vector3 (x+x') (y+y') (z+z')
```

But ghci complains about ambiguous occurrence of `(+)`. I do not understand why the occurrence is ambiguous; surely the type checker can infer that `x`, `x'`, `y` etc have type `Double` and hence the correct operator to use for them is `Prelude.+`?

I know that I could make `Vector3` an instance of the `Num` typeclass, but that is too restrictive for me; I do not want to define multiplication of a vector by another vector.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only way to overload a name in Haskell is to use type classes, so you have three choices:

- Make `Vector` an instance of `Num` and just have multiplication return an `error`.
- Use something like [the numeric prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude), which defines more fine-grained numeric classes.
- Pick some other name like `.+.` or something similar for vector addition.

Comment: thanks for pointing to numeric prelude; do you know any place it is documented?

Comment: @zodiac: Reference documentation is available on the link I posted, just scroll to the bottom and click on a module name. [Algebra.Additive](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/numeric-prelude/0.2.2.1/doc/html/Algebra-Additive.html) looks like a good place to start for this example of adding vectors.

Comment: Conal Elliott's `vector-space` package is much more lightweight than `numeric-prelude`. For adding vectors define an instance of `AdditiveGroup`.

Comment: thank you all for your helpful answers; but does anyone know why the occurrence of (+) is ambiguous (ie my code actually works if I use "Prelude.+" and "Main.+"

Comment: @zodiac: It's ambiguous because you have two `(+)` in scope. One that you defined yourself, and the one from the Prelude. So without qualification, the compiler does not know which one you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that I could make `Vector3` an instance of the `Num` typeclass, but that is too restrictive for me; I do not want to define multiplication of a vector by another vector.

That would be the easiest solution, though. You can define multiplication as

```
(*)  =  error "vector multiplication not implemented"
```

Think of the vector operations that you would get for free!

Comment: You actually don't need any parameters. `error :: String -> a`.

Comment: You get `-` if you define `negate`. You get `sum`. Okay, maybe not that great, but typeclasses are the "proper" way of overloading in Haskell.

Comment: The main problem with making vectors a `Num` instance is that you _would_ like to define a multiplication, but not as `Vector->Vector->Vector` but as `Field->Vector->Vector` or `Num a => a->Vector->Vector`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with defining multiplication as scalar product, and to use another operator for multiplication with a scalar.

Comment: @Landei I believe that (*) under Num would have type v -> v -> v so I would have to define (*) as vector product?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "dot product" for normal v -> v -> v multiplication.

Comment: @Landei The result of a dot product is not a vector, but a scalar. Hence the comments about the type being wrong.